# Replace the first few observations of a sparse matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, sparse-matrix, tidyr

I have the following data which looks like the following:

```
       col1      col2        
  [1,] "group 5" "BNDBP6569M"
  [2,] "group 3" "MMCRO7403D"
  [3,] "group 3" "QFMVN5837D"
  [4,] "group 3" "JEXQH9565P"
  [5,] "group 3" "VEGAE7145C"
  [6,] "group 1" "JHRQM4424S"
  [7,] "group 2" "HNABS7216I"
```

I put it into sparse format which looks like:

```
[1,] NA . . . 1 . . 1 . . . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . .
[2,] NA . 1 . . 1 . . . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . . . .
[3,] NA 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . 1 1 . . . . 1 . . . 1
[4,] NA . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . 1 .
[5,] NA . . 1 . . 1 . . . . . . 1 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . 1 1 . .
```

When I create this sparse matrix I obtain a warning:

```
Warning message:
In storage.mode(from) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Which essentially replaces the `group n` with an `NA` value. I am trying to rename the first `n` rows to the length of the `names` character vector using `dat_sparse@x <- names`. However it is not really doing what I want.

How can I include the names of the groups as "identifyer" rows without obtaining NA values?

**Data:**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(Matrix)

library(rsample)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)


names <- c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4")
col1 <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)

col1 <- paste("group", col1)

myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}
col2 <- myFun(100)
col2


dat <- cbind(col1, col2)
dat

dat_sparse <- dat %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(col1, col2) %>%
  spread(col2, n, fill = 0) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  Matrix(., sparse = TRUE)

dat_sparse
```

EDIT:

I think the problem comes down to the last two lines here:

```
dat_sparse <- dat %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(col1, col2) %>%
  spread(col2, n, fill = 0) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  Matrix(., sparse = TRUE)
```

Setting rownames to a `Matrix()` object was returing warnings and NA values. Simply removing the `Matrix()` step here and running the following:

```
dat_sparse <- dat %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(col1, col2) %>%
  spread(col2, n, fill = 0) %>%
  as.matrix()

rownames(dat_sparse) <- dat_sparse[,1]
dat_spares <- dat_sparse[,-c(1)]
new_mat <- Matrix(dat_spares)
```

Seems to work. The `new_mat` looks like:

```
group 1 . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 1
group 2 1 . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . 1 . 1 . . 1 . . . .
group 3 . 1 . 1 . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . 1 1 . . 1 . .
group 4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
group 5 . . . . . . . 1 . 1 1 . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . .
```

Where `group 1, group 2 etc.` are the rownames.

Comment: Is the function "Matrix" coming from "Matrix" library? Please clarify which libraries are loaded.

Comment: ah apologies! I used `library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(Matrix)

library(rsample)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)`

Comment: Then please edit your post.

Comment: The Matrix package does not offer sparse character matrices. I don't understand that tidyverse mumbo-jumbo, but it appears you are trying to put character values into a numeric Matrix. That is simply not possible.

Comment: However, a Matrix can have rownames and colnames.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and set the row names equal to the character values. `rownames(dat_sparse@x) <- names`

Comment: It should work if the number of names matches the number of rows.

Comment: No, it should be `rownames(dat_sparse) <- names`.

Comment: I think the problem now comes from these two lines `as.matrix() %>%
  Matrix(., sparse = TRUE)`

Comment: I think this solved the issue... `rownames(dat_sparse) <- dat_sparse[,1]
dat_spares <- dat_sparse[,-c(1)]

new_mat <- Matrix(dat_spares)  `

Comment: The problem was arising when I tried to rename the rownames when the matrix was a sparse matrix. I edit my original post to better explain.

Comment: If your last EDIT is the solution, then post as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `tidy` solution.

```
dat_sparse <- dat %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(col1, col2) %>%
  spread(col2, n, fill = 0) %>%
  column_to_rownames("col1") %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  Matrix(., sparse = TRUE)

dat_sparse
```

Output:

```
group 1 . . . 1 . 1 . . 1 . . . . . . 1 1 . . 1 . . . . . . . . .
group 2 . 1 . . . . . . . 1 1 . . . 1 . . 1 1 . . . . 1 . . . 1 .
group 3 1 . 1 . . . 1 1 . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 1 . . 1
group 4 . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . .
group 5 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . .
```